# Complete solutions to $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \alpha_1} + \cdots + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \alpha_n} = 0$.

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, roots-of-unity

Let $n \geq 1$.
Assume that $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in [0,2\pi)$ are numbers such that
\begin{equation} 
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \alpha_1} + \cdots + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \alpha_n} = 0.  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
As is well-known, if we set $\alpha_k = \beta + \frac{2  k \pi}{n}$ for some $\alpha$, we obtain a solution. The same of course holds by permuting the indices.
Then, writing $n = m_1 + \cdots + m_p$ and if one choses, for each $1 \leq q \leq p$, the $m_q$ equispaced angles including a fixed $\beta_q$, and we set uses those $m_1 + \ldots + m_q = n$  angles for the $\alpha_k$, then
\begin{equation} 
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \alpha_1} + \cdots + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \alpha_n} = \sum_{q=1}^p \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \beta_q}\sum_{j=1}^{m_q} \mathrm{e}^{ {2\mathrm{i} \pi j} /{m_q}} =0 ,  
\end{equation}
because each $\sum_{j=1}^{m_q} \mathrm{e}^{ {2\mathrm{i} \pi j} /{m_q}} = 0$ as a sum of roots of unity.

**Question:** Are the described angles (up to permutation) the only solutions to (1)?

Of course, it makes a large set of solutions, but relatively easy to describe and I could not find any other solution.

Comment: It is the same as creating an $n$-gon all of whose sides have length one.  And intuitively you can see this has a tremendous number of solutions, certainly a lot more than you presented.

Comment: There are many more solutions. For example, one family of solutions consists of $2n+1$ vectors, with $n$ vectors with angle $\alpha$, $n$ vectors with $-\alpha$, where $\sin(\alpha) = \frac 1 {2n}$, and the last vector as $(-1, 0)$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith That's correct and convincing: one can visualize the freedom for an $n$-gon that goes back to the origin with length one size. Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't want the $i$ in "$\alpha_k = \beta + 2ik \pi/n$"

Comment: @aschepler I updated it, thanks.